# The Deployment "nodejs-deployment" is invalid spec.template.metadata.labels: Invalid value

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, deployment

I'm new in Kubernetes and I was tring to deploy a nodejs service to kubernetes. For that I created a docker image and upload it to dockerhub and finally I created a deployment file that contains all required configurations in order to accomplish the deployment.
The deployment file is shown above. I then executed the command 'kubectl apply -f deployment_local.yaml' and I came across with this error: "*spec.template.metadata.labels:Invalid value map[string]string{"app":"nodejs\u00a0\u00a0"}:`selector` does not match template `labels`"

I'm tring to fix this bug but I could not fix it. Pls help understand this error because I'm strugglying for a lot of time.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nodejs-deployment
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nodejs
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nodejs  
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nodeapp
        image: lucasseabra/nodejs-starter
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nodejs-entrypoint
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: nodejs
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
    nodePort: 30001
```

Comment: Is it just a pasting error or have you not mentioned an `apiVersion` for your Deployment altogether?

Comment: Sorry it's a pasting error because I have that line. Thanks tho

Comment: Do you have any existing deployments by the same name (nodejs-deployment) ?

Comment: No and after a some research I tipped 'kubectl get svc' and it appears 2 services. One is kubernetes and the other is nodejs-entrypoint

Comment: Can't reproduce the error, It's working for me. Something wrong in your environment perhaps. Run `kubectl delete -f deployment_local.yaml` once and try to apply again.

Comment: God damn it, it runned that command it appears to me the following: service "nodejs-entrypoint" deleted   Error from server (NotFound): error when deleting "deployment_local.yaml": deployments.apps "nodejs-deployment" not found

Comment: Then I run again 'kubectl apply -f deployment_local.yaml' and it shows the error again. My question is, is it possible the despite this error apperars my service is running?

Comment: No, the service might be creating but your deployment is failing. Can you describe your environment for me please.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what you mean by my environment. My k8s enviroment? I simply run minikube start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message was trying to tell you, there are two ["non-breaking space" characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Encodings) after `nodejs`: `map[string]string{"app":"nodejs\u00a0\u00a0"}`

I would guess it was a side-effect of copy-pasting from a webpage

If you even do a "select all" on your posted question here, you'll see that SO has converted the two characters into normal spaces, but they do show up in the selection extension past the "nodejs" text

If your editor is not able to show you the characters, then either manually retype the labels, or try copying this (which is just yours but with trailing spaces removed)

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nodejs-deployment
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nodejs
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nodejs
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nodeapp
        image: lucasseabra/nodejs-starter
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nodejs-entrypoint
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: nodejs
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
    nodePort: 30001
```

Comment: Thanks man! It was ended the problem you described, back in time I used a code...much thanks to you :D